# Convert SQL query to Linq query with left outer join and where clause

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I want to convert this SQL query to a Linq query

```
select 
    prsnRolIDTitle, prprdID
from 
    Tbl_RoleDetail
left outer join 
    Tbl_PersonRolPersonRolDetail on Tbl_RoleDetail.prsnRolDID = Tbl_PersonRolPersonRolDetail.prsnRolDID
                                 and Tbl_PersonRolPersonRolDetail.prsnRolID = 6
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
    from  rd in  Tbl_RoleDetail
    from Tbl_PersonRolPersonRolDetail.Where(t => t.prsnRolID = 6 && t.prsnRolDID == rd.prsnRolDID).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {rd.prsnRolIDTitle, prd.prprdID}
```